# APNS notification opens the app and displays where we left off

Tags: ios, push-notification

My app is running in the background on settings screen, upon selecting the APNS notification it opens the app and display where we left off. (Happens only when the app is running in the background)

Is it the APNS Payload which is causing this or the app is not supporting it? What should i look for in the device logs? Any references will be helpful, I am a newbie.

Thanks,

Comment: There is nothing special happening, the behaviour is same when you launch the app normally from background it stays in the last screen as app was running in background not killed, so when you tap on notification it just launches your app, and since it was in background it shows last state, kill the app and do the same it won't open last screen for you. Hope its clear.

Comment: if you want to open particular screen on tap of notification then you need to implement that code in appDelegate's didReciveNotification method. you need to check application state, Active,InActive and other and do what you want to  do on tap of notification.

Answer (score 0):

Hi As for as my under standing, if you want open your app via notification at the same time the app is not running at the back end, you could write the following code in you `AppDelegate - didFinishLaunchingOption`

```
NSDictionary* notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

if (notification && [notification isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && notification.allKeys.count) {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSDictionary *apsInfo = notification[@"aps"];
        DLog(@"backGround Push == %@", apsInfo);
        if (apsInfo && [apsInfo isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && apsInfo.allKeys.count) {
            NSInteger redirectScreen = [apsInfo[@"redirectTo"] integerValue]; // redirectTo - is a custom option. This will help for screen redirection identification
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I want this to happen in the opposite way. I want to open the app using APNS notification when the app is running in the background. Also, it should not take me to the screen where I left of.

Comment: See the above code will work, even in your app is in background running mode and also the app is not active state too. If you want to avoid the screen that where you left mean you have to access your root controller and then based on the 'redirectScreen' you will navigate 

redirectScreen is a custom option, like based on event set the value on it. Based on value navigate the appropriate controller.